# Syntax error after running every command in tmux

Tags: command-line, bash

I am getting the same error after executing every command in `tmux` and after running it, and this is annoying:

```
-bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
-bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: `preexec_set_exit;__bp_precmd_invoke_cmd; dbus-send --type=method_call --session --dest=net.launchpad.pantheon-terminal /net/launchpad/pantheon_terminal org.pantheon.terminal.ProcessFinished string:$PANTHEON_TERMINAL_ID string:"$(history 1 | cut -c 8-)" >/dev/null 2>&1;  __bp_interactive_mode;;preexec_invoke_cmd'
```

Though when I am using just `bash`, I am not getting this error.

What can cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Using an editor such as nano or vim, Add the line

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

to your `.bashrc` file, and it will take effect on the next session.

To apply the change immediately for the life of the current shell session, type

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

in your terminal window.